# How to get each row size of a particular table in postgresql..?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to get each row size of a particular table in postgres?

For example a table has 50 rows and total table size is 10gb but i want to know each row size rather than complete table size.

Answer (score 54):

Function to calculate row size of postgress table row is something like this

```
SELECT sum(pg_column_size(t.*)) as filesize, count(*) as filerow FROM TABLE_NAME as t;
```

replace `TABLE_NAME` with your table name;
to add condition `t.COLUMN_NAME = 'YOUR_VALUE'`

Comment: Nice one. Note that `pg_column_size(t.*)` can be simplified to `pg_column_size(t)`. That value will include the row header "overhead", so to get the actual data size, you need to subtract 24: `pg_column_size(t) - 24`

Comment: In case it saves someone a quick lookup, the value return here is the size in bytes.

Answer (score 10):

There is no function that calculates the size of a row, only a function that calculates the size of a column value. So you can do something like this:

```
select pg_column_size(column_1) + 
       pg_column_size(column_2) + 
       pg_column_size(column_3) as row_size
from the_table;
```

This could be automated using dynamic SQL and a PL/pgSQL function if you need this.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i run this query for all rows in  a table.can you help me in providing the dyanamic query.?

Comment: @DeepeshGoel: that will run for all _rows_ in the table because it has no `where` clause

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you also share what is the unit of the output? is it bytes?

Comment: @aquaman [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#id-1.5.8.33.9.3.2.2.1.1.1.1)  "*Shows the number of bytes used to store any individual data value*"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the size of a specific row or with the where clause returning only 1 row, try below -

```
select pg_column_size(table_name.*) as rowsize_in_bytes from table_name where id = '698119855102848';
```