# PostgreSQL column size vs table size

Tags: database, postgresql, size

I am trying to get only one table size, and then size of each row.
While I was using

```
SELECT pg_table_size(*mytable*) as DATA;
```

I get 393216 bytes.

Using

```
SELECT (SUM(pg_column_size(t) - 24)) FROM *mytable* AS t;
```

(as written here [How to get each row size of a particular table in postgresql..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222996/how-to-get-each-row-size-of-a-particular-table-in-postgresql))

I get 560669 bytes.

560669 vs 393216 bytes - which one is real?

Comment: The goal is - get REAL value of each row, then get REAL value of all rows. I need to access this..

Comment: Does the TOAST table contain data?

Comment: I can only see "TOAST" as schema - so toast and toast_temp are both empty.

Comment: I am talking about the table you can find with `SELECT reltoastrelid::regclass FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'mytable';`

Comment: Ups, my fault. Yeah, it's empty. // edited: Another fault. It's not, I've used query with schema included. Without schema - it has one row as a result.

Comment: I cannot reproduce or explain your result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-admin.html

> pg_table_size - Computes the disk space used by the specified table,
> excluding indexes (but including its TOAST table if any, free space
> map, and visibility map).

So pg_table_size gives you the amount of disk postgres is using for the table and for some metadata that postgres keeps about the table ([Visibility Map](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-vm.html) and [Free Space Map](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-fsm.html)). [Deleting a row will not decrease this number](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220701/vacuum-did-not-reduce-reported-size-of-database) (unless you do a VACUUM FULL), so we wouldn't expect the disk used by a table to match the sum of the data in each visible row. Instead, the disk used by a table would be larger.

> pg_column_size - Shows the number of bytes used to store any individual
> data value. If applied directly to a table column value, this reflects
> any compression that was done.

So this returns the size of each row on disk (including the row-header information stored on disk).

I'm not sure whether you'd consider the row header information 'real', but it does take up space on your harddrive, so whether this is correct or not depends on your use case.

Using an example table from a database I have:

```sql
SELECT pg_table_size('users')
-- 3751936 <-- the size of my 'users' table on disk, including table meta-data
SELECT (SUM(pg_column_size(t.*))) FROM users AS t;
-- 3483028 <-- the total size on disk of the visible rows, including row "header" metadata.
SELECT (SUM(pg_column_size(t.*)-24)) FROM users AS t;
-- 3069412 <-- the size of the data in visible rows, excluding row "header" meta-data
```

We'd expect each of these queries to return different numbers, and each is useful for a different purpose.

As for the specific numbers that you've posted (with the `pg_column_size` being larger than the `pg_table_size`) I can't explain.

Comment: I agree. So in my case there's no way to get all of the taken memory by a table, and then exactly the same memory but separated for each row. Thanks a lot for a explanation.